# Core Data Save Error: Non-Optional Properties disappear during Save attempt

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Context: I set multiple non-optional properties of a CoreData Object and received an error after attempting save.

Specifically, "fbid" and "owner" are correctly set before attempting Save. After a save attempt, they are indicated to be nil as shown in the print() and error excerpts below.
What am I doing incorrectly here? And what could be the cause of this problem?

**Print statement of Core Data Object before attempting save**

```
<HittupMe.Hittup: 0x1740db6d0> (entity: Hittup; id: 0x174a2dca0 <x-coredata:///Hittup/tE7827F40-D3F7-4CA3-AB73-133466C994E62> ; data: {
fbid = 5692f3bfda68df8e3f831177;
...
owner = "0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://D4C715E1-EEBF-4E2C-96B6-8A8C692F852C/User/p1>";
...
usersJoined = "<relationship fault: 0x174a36c00 'usersJoined'>";
})
```

**Error: After managedContext.save()**

```
[NSValidationErrorKey: owner, NSLocalizedDescription: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.), NSValidationErrorObject: <HittupMe.Hittup: 0x1740db970> (entity: Hittup; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://D4C715E1-EEBF-4E2C-96B6-8A8C692F852C/Hittup/p1> ; data: {
fbid = nil;
...
owner = nil;
...
usersJoined = "<relationship fault: 0x174a36c00 'usersJoined'>";
})]
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a test case?  If not then there is something wrong in your code, if so, post the test case so others can explore it.  Without some code to look at there is not much chance someone is going to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was **"One-to-one"** relationship set in schema where a **"One-to-many"** relationship was needed

Ex: In my code, I saved multiple objects with a relationship to the same instance of an "User" object. Since my schema was set to be one-to-one, only one object could be set to a user at a time, resulting in some objects with a nil owner.